# Fine Uploader scaled image naming pattern

Tags: fine-uploader

I am using the scaling image functionaliy of Fine Uploader and want to tweak it a little bit.

Let's say I have this configuration (from [here](http://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/features/scaling.html))

```
scaling: {
    sizes: [
        {name: "small", maxSize: 100}
    ]
}
```

If I provide a file named `image.png` Fine Uploader is going to create a scaled version of my image according to the above configuration and give it the name `image (small).png`.

I am looking for a way to change this naming pattern - so that I get a custom name of the files which are sent to the server - for example `small_image.png` or similar. I want to achieve this at the Fine Uploader/browser/client side and not on my backend.

Any other (undocumented) option available besides forking the repo and introducing the change myself?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question. what specifically are you trying to do?

Comment: @RayNicholus I edited the question

Comment: There isn't a way to change the naming convention at the moment. If you'd like to see this, I would suggest deleting this question from SO and opening a feature request in the proeject's issue tracker.